# moving data from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, tabs

I am looking for a way to move data from several spreadsheet tabs into one tab. All of the tabs have similar, if not the same column headings but are not in the same position. Copying and pasting would require a lot of manual manipulate. Is there a formula or code I can use to move data from tabs “1-20” into tab “21” with the data in the same columns? 
Tab 21 (end result)
ITEM    Price   Cost    value   description

Tabs 1 example

```
ITEM    Price   Cost    value   description
```

Tab 15 example

```
ITEM    cost    description price
```

Tab 18 example

```
Description  cost   value
```

Answer (score 0):

Check answer for this question:
[How to import data from one sheet to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634987/how-to-import-data-from-one-sheet-to-another)

VLookup can solve your problem